# EDI to XML converting using XSLT

Tags: java, xml, xslt, edi

Hi I am trying to convert EDI to xml using xslt. The edi I am trying to convert

```
B3**123456789**MX**20060701*6141****FDE*20061121*B1
LX*1 
L11*333333333333*AW*925*20060622
L11*900*RU
L11*123*BT 
L11*114114114*IT 
L11*23*454*44 
L11*78*9
L11*45*566*45
L11*D*AHC 
N1*RI*EDX ERS
N3*PAYMENT*ADDRESS
N4*CITY*PA*152507741*IN

LX*2 
L11*222222222222*AW*1117*20050622
L11*1*9W
L11*900*RU
L11*445*7874*44 
L11*12*988
L11*98*5786*45
L11*D*AHC 
N3*PAYMENT*ADDRESS
N4*CITY*PA*152507741*IN
```

I am trying to get each L11 values under LX separately.
What I tried to do is to loop through the LX tags, but under the first LX*1 tag all the L11 values even those under LX*2 are coming. But for LX*2 only the ones under is populating.

```
<xsl:for-each select="$B3/following-sibling::LX[position() &gt; 0]">

<xsl:for-each select="$LX/following-sibling::L1[position() &gt; 0]">

getting each of the L11 tags
```

First loop for each LX and second for each L11 for LX. So where i am going wrong?.

Comment: Your input file doesn't look like proper XML...

Comment: @GyroGearless The input file is not xml. Its in EDI format

Comment: My understanding of XSLT is that it is used to transform XML documents into HTML or another XML document.  XSLT uses XPATH and the Document Object Model in order to find the xml elements to be processed.  Does XSLT work on objects outside the DOM?